# How to separate two  plots in R?

Tags: r, plot

Whenever I run this code , the first plot would simply overwrite the previous one. Isnt there a way in R to separate to get two plots ?

```
plot(pc)
title(main='abc',xlab='xx',ylab='yy')

plot(pcs)
title(main='sdf',xlab='sdf',ylab='xcv')
```

Answer (score 39):

If you just want to see two different plotting windows open at the same time, use `dev.new`, e.g.

```
plot(1:10)
dev.new()
plot(10:1)
```

If you want to draw two plots in the same window then, as Shane mentioned, set the `mfrow` parameter.

```
par(mfrow = c(2,1))
plot(1:10)
plot(10:1)
```

If you want to try something a little more advanced, then you can take a look at lattice graphics or ggplot, both of which are excellent for creating conditioned plots (plots where different subsets of data appear in different frames).

A lattice example:

```
library(lattice)
dfr <- data.frame(
  x   = rep(1:10, 2), 
  y   = c(1:10, 10:1), 
  grp = rep(letters[1:2], each = 10)
)
xyplot(y ~ x | grp, data = dfr)
```

A ggplot example.  (You'll need to download ggplot from CRAN first.)

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x, y, data = dfr, facets = grp ~ .)
#or equivalently
ggplot(dfr, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(grp ~ .)
```

Comment: Gotta give some love to the `mfcol` parameter. It fills your plots column-wise which is in line with how every other object in R is filled (well, mainly matrices). Just discovered it. Had always been wondering why plots are filled row-wise... don't think I'll ever go back to `mfrow`!

Answer (score 15):

Try using `par` before you plot.

```
 par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also try the layout command:

Try 
       `layout(1:2)`

```
plot(A)    
plot(B)
```

Answer (score 2):

try command `x11()` before each plot, here's an example:

```
x11()
plot(1:10)
x11()
plot(rnorm(10))
```

This will lead to different plot windows. You can add "par" command to any of these `x11()` windows and get more variety of plots, i.e. 4 plots in one window while a big plot in another window.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 2 plots in separate windows or files you can select new devices before calling each plot command.  See:

> ?Devices

And,

> ?dev.cur

Comment: oh ok , thanks for all the great suggestions guys, 
learned something new again .

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer is to assign the plot as an object, then you can display it when you want
i.e

```
abcplot<-plot(pc) title(main='abc',xlab='xx',ylab='yy')

sdfplot<-plot(pcs) title(main='sdf',xlab='sdf',ylab='xcv')

abcplot # Displays the abc plot
sdfplot # Displays the sdf plot
abcplot # Displays the abc plot again
```

Comment: This does not work. `plot` returns `NULL`.  You cannot save the details of the graph this way. If you use `grid`-based graphics (e.g. `lattice`), what you suggest is possible, e.g. `p1 <- xyplot(y~x); print(p1)`.