# How to separate linear regression plots in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression

For a linear model with 2 variables

```
r = lm(y ~ x1+x2)
```

When I run  `plot(r)` , I get a bunch of plots such as residuals vs fitted values and so on , but I can only look at one of them at a time .

Isn't there a way to separate them ?

Comment: What are you asking about? Matlab? Sth else?

Comment: ohw nvm ,this seems to work with   par(mfrow=c(2,1)) aswell, learned something new again .

Comment: Right. No different than your other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801064/how-to-separate-two-plots-in-r.  Maybe delete this one?

Answer (score 5):

A few ways.  The most convenient is layout.  `?layout` for more details

```
r<-lm(y~x1+x2)
layout(matrix(1:4,2,2))
plot(r)
```

will produce a window with four plots.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the line:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
```

before

```
plot(r)
```

In that way you say to R to show 4 pictures at the same frame. You can also set 4,1 to have 4 graphs one above the other, or 1,4 to have 4 graphs one on the side of the other.