# text wordcloud plotting error

Tags: r, word-cloud

I have the following code for plotting a word cloud, and am getting the subsequent error.

```
wordcloud(dm$word, dm$freq, scale=c(8,.2),min.freq=2,
+           max.words=Inf, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=.15, colors=rainbow

>Warning message:
In wordcloud(dm$word, dm$freq, scale = c(8, 0.2), min.freq = 2,:health insurance could not be fit on page. It will not be plotted. Unable to view plot.
```

I do not understand why this is happening.  Please help.

Comment: Try with a smaller scale e.g. `scale = c(4, 0.2)` or with less words : `max.words = 30` for example.

Comment: Perhaps before wordcloud you gsub() "health insurance" to "hlth ins." so it fits on the scale you want with the number of words you want.

Comment: Thank a lot. smaller scale worked.

Answer (score 14):

Try with smaller scale, for example:

```
wordcloud(Election2016Corpus, max.words =100,min.freq=3,scale=c(4,.5), 
           random.order = FALSE,rot.per=.5,vfont=c("sans serif","plain"),colors=palette())
```

Answer (score 6):

You may also try [plotting with a larger device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2129952/3163618), for example

```
dev.new(width = 1000, height = 1000, unit = "px")
wordcloud(...)
```

see the link for other ways to plot a certain size.

Answer (score 1):

`wordcloud2(dm)` might work. 
you can install wordcloud2 package and just one

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read about [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Your post doesn't provide an answer to the question. It's more a comment.

Comment: BEWARE, wordcloud2 suffers from the same problem but drops words that don't fit silently.