# Setting the size of the graphics window (plot size) in R

Tags: r, plot, graphics

```
plot.new()
segments(0, 1, 3)
segments(0, 0.5, 2)
```

I tried plotting 2 lines, but it seems like my plot size is too small (so the two lines appear to be the same length). I've tried the following in reference to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129952/creating-a-plot-window-of-a-particular-size) but couldn't get the desired result:

```
> dev.new(height = 3, width = 3)
NULL
> segments(0, 1, 3)
Error in segments(0, 1, 3) : plot.new has not been called yet
> segments(0, 0.5, 2)
Error in segments(0, 0.5, 2) : plot.new has not been called yet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize an empty plot and then put your line segments into this plot:

```
# empty plot
plot(NULL, ylim=c(-1,2), xlim=c(-1,4), ylab="something", xlab="the x axis")
# add line segments
segments(0, 1, 3)
segments(0, 0.5, 2)
```

This produces

[image]

To remove everything except the line segments, start with

```
plot(NULL, ylim=c(-1,2), xlim=c(-1,4), ylab="", xlab="", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", bty="n")
```

You can find references to each of these arguments in the `help(par)` file.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to have just the segments and nothing else? (no box, no axes, etc)