# R Gui: Create plot window bigger than the default par("din")

Tags: r, rgui

In Windows R Gui, I am trying to create plot window bigger than the default one. I am using `dev.new()` for this purpose (see [Creating a Plot Window of a Particular Size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2129952/684229)), but it just doesn't create window bigger than the default din parameter (which cannot be set):

```
dev.off()
par("din")
dev.off()
# [1] 6.641667 6.633333 <---- THIS IS THE DEFAULT WINDOW SIZE
dev.new(width = 10, height = 10)
par("din")
# [1] 6.641666 6.633332 <---- STILL THE SAME!
```

It works for smaller windows though:

```
dev.off()
dev.new(width = 3, height = 3)
par("din")
# [1] 2.991666 2.983333 <--- it works for smaller than the default
```

Why it doesn't work for dimensions bigger than the default and how do I make it work?

Comment: does `x11()` work? On ubuntu, I can set window size with `x11` but not with `dev.new`

Comment: @RichardTelford with "Windows R Gui", I mean MS Windows, not X Windows :-)

Comment: What does `getOption("device")` return? That is the device `dev.new` will call and give the ... to

Comment: @RichardTelford it returns some function

Comment: You need to look at how that function handles height and width arguments