# R - plot of spatial data plus outline from shapefile

Tags: r, plot, shapefile

I am trying to map point density estimates of fish on a map of a lake, to then run geostatistical analyses on.

I have read in a shapefile of the outline of a lake by using `readOGR` function from `rgdal`, successfully. This object I named `lake`

My density estimates of fish, along with coordinates is in a db class object named `db.data`. I can plot my density estimates of fish with the line:

```r
plot(db.data)
```

When I then overlay my `lake` on the plot of fish density estimates, with code `plot(lake, add=T)` the entire extent of the lake does not show up. Instead, it is cropped.

How do I get the entire outline of the lake shapefile to show up in this plot?

Comment: Could you post your code so far? It might be that the size of your plot isn't big enough. Try manually setting it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129952/creating-a-plot-window-of-a-particular-size

Comment: Thanks, got it to work by manually setting it.

Now I would like to set the extent of the shapefile in view on this plot to a polygon object. My next step is to select only the fish samples which are included in the polygon.

My code so far is:
fish <- read.csv("C/...")
reservoir <- readOGR("C/...")
db.data=db.create(fish)
plot(db.data, ylim=c(), xlim=c())
plot(reservoir, add=T)

db.data=db.polygon(db.data, reservoir)
The input object is of type ' SpatialPolygonsDataFrame '. It should be of type ' polygon '
The function is interrupted
Error: Invalid object type