# Why the Plot Window's size stay unchanged in R?

Tags: r

At present there are two problems:

**Problem 1:**
This problem has been solevd thanks to @Humpelstielzchen, it's because the "noRStudioGD = TRUE" issue.

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129952/creating-a-plot-window-of-a-particular-size), and tried Shane's answer, which is:

```
# the plot with width=5
dev.new(width=5, height=4)
plot(1:20)
```

Then I tried to change the width from 5 to 10, to see if there is some different:

```
# the plot with width=10
dev.new(width=10, height=4)
plot(1:20)
```

but it seems no change of the picture's size at all ([image: see here]). Why does this happen?

**Problem 2:**
I changed the `units =` (cm or inch), but the [image: Plot Window] seems unchanged. More strangely, the width of these two windows is 23.2 cm, the height is 10.5 cm: these vaules are neither 10 cm or 10 inch for width, and 4 cm or 4 inch for height.

```
# units = "cm"
dev.new(width=10, height=4, noRStudioGD = TRUE, units = "cm")
plot(1:20, main = "units = cm")

# units = "inch"
dev.new(width=10, height=4, noRStudioGD = TRUE, units = "inch")
plot(1:20, main = "units = inch")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do

```
dev.new(width=10, height=4, noRStudioGD = TRUE, units = "cm")
plot(1:20)
```

They apparently changed the behaviour of `dev.new()` in RStudio some time ago.

There is also something about it in the description: `? dev.new`

Comment: Now the two plots have different width. But the `"width=10"` plot seems not the width of 10 inch: I used a ruler to measure it, it's 23 cm width. It should be 25.4 cm width of the plot window.

Comment: that's because the default unit is inches. Try my update.

Comment: I checked the "units = " option, but a problem occurred (see **Problem 2** in my updated question)

Comment: that's a good question. Others had the same problem but I didn't find a reason or solution. Have you tried saving the plot to a file and checking measurements there?

Comment: I saved them to "png" file, and their width are all 15.5 cm, height are 6.2 cm. This time, the aspect ratio (15.5:6.2 = 2.5) is strictly the same as the original set (10:4 = 2.5). This is better than the plot directly shown in RStudio (23.2:10.5 = 2.21). Although the "absolue" width or height still doesn't meet with the code.