# How to visualize Markov chains for NLP using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, nlp, visualization, markov-chains

I am working on analyzing some text in R and have settled on (for the moment) Markov chains as part of my procedure. Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
# Required libraries
library(stringi)      # Input cleaning
library(tidyverse)    # dplyr, ggplot, etc.
library(hunspell)     # Spell checker
library(markovchain)  # Markov chain calculation
# Input
shake <- c("To be, or not to be - that is the question: Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune Or to take arms against a sea of troubles And by opposing end them.")

# Process to clean input
miniclean <- function(x = ""){
        # x is character string input
        words_i = x %>% 
        gsub(pattern = "[^[:alpha:][:space:]\']", replacement = "") %>%
        #gsub(pattern = "[\n]+", replacement = "") %>%   # Drop line breaks
        stri_trans_tolower() %>%
        strsplit(split = " ") %>%
        unlist() 
        
        correct = hunspell_check(words_i)
        words_o = words_i[correct]
        
        return(words_o)
}

# Clean input
cleans <- miniclean(shake)

# Compute Markov chain using cleaned input
mark2 <- markovchainFit(cleans)

# Plot results
plot(mark2$estimate)
```

The base `plot` graphics produces this visualization:

[image]

I would really like a bit more control over the plot (e.g., increasing arrow lengths to increase the overall size to make it more readable), but I don't see how to do it.

Ideas?

(edited to make a complete example)

Comment: Read the code of the function.

Comment: This code doesn't produce this figure for me. Check your code as supplied and update? (for example, where does `cleans` come from?)

Comment: What packages are you using? Where does `markovchainFit` come from?

Comment: @phalteman - I've updated this to be a complete example that can be run.

Comment: It seems like your plot window is too small. Have you tried [increasing the plot window size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2129952/8366499) to see if that makes it look better?

Comment: @divibisan - Yes, I have.