# How can I produce a "symmetrical" contour plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I'm plotting a bivariate circular normal distribution in R:

```
library(MASS)
library(mnormt)
set.seed(0)

# create bivariate normal distribution
x     <- seq(-4, 4, 0.1) 
y     <- seq(-4, 4, 0.1)
mu    <- c(0, 0)
sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1), nrow=2)
f     <- function(x, y) dmnorm(cbind(x, y), mu, sigma)
z     <- outer(x, y, f)

# create contour plot
contour(x,y,z)
```

[image]

The contours should be circular, but instead they are elliptical because the width of the plot > the height of the plot.

What I've tried:

- I consulted the for [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/contour) the function but didn't notice any argument that could be set.
- I think ggplot2 accomplishes a fixed aspect ratio via the [coord_fixed](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_fixed.html) function - but again, I don't see anything similar for the `contour` function
- I set `dev.new(width=5, height=5)` as recommended by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2129970/1958215) but it didn't change anything (maybe I'm implementing it incorrectly).

So, is there a simple way to enforce circular contours using the `contour` function (I'm guessing there is since it feels like a pretty basic need), or should I just switch over to using ggplot2?

Comment: `contour(x,y,z, asp=1)` - see `?plot.default` help. I'm pretty sure there's a duplicate question for this somewhere.

Comment: aha - yes, that answers my question, thanks very much