# How to Plot "Reverse" Cumulative Frequency Graph With ECDF

Tags: r, statistics

I have no problem plotting the following cumulative **frequency** graph plot
like this.

```
     library(Hmisc)
     pre.test <- rnorm(100,50,10)
     post.test <- rnorm(100,55,10)
     x <- c(pre.test, post.test)
     g <- c(rep('Pre',length(pre.test)),rep('Post',length(post.test)))
     Ecdf(x, group=g, what="f", xlab='Test Results', label.curves=list(keys=1:2))
```

But I want to show the graph in forms of the "reverse" cumulative frequency of values > x.
(i.e. something equivalent to what="1-f").

Is there a way to do it?

Other suggestions in R other than using Hmisc are also very much welcomed.

Comment: Hi. I remove unix/linux tags from your both question cause they are independent from OS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Musa suggestion:

```
pre.ecdf <- ecdf(pre.test)
post.ecdf <- ecdf(post.test)

r <- range(pre.test,post.test)
curve(1-pre.ecdf(x), from=r[1], to=r[2], col="red", xlim=r)
curve(1-post.ecdf(x), from=r[1], to=r[2], col="blue", add=TRUE)
```

[image: Proportions]

You could set some parameters like title, legend, etc.

If you want frequency instead of proportion simple solution will be:

```
pre.ecdf <- ecdf(pre.test)
post.ecdf <- ecdf(post.test)

rx <- range(pre.test,post.test)
ry <- max(length(pre.test),length(post.test))
curve(length(pre.test)*(1-pre.ecdf(x)), from=rx[1], to=rx[2], col="red", xlim=rx, ylim=c(0,ry))
curve(length(post.test)*(1-post.ecdf(x)), from=rx[1], to=rx[2], col="blue", add=TRUE)
```

[image: Frequencies]

Comment: @Marek: As I mentioned in OP or to Dirk. What I am looking for is the reverse cumulative "frequency" plot not "proportion".

Answer (score 5):

The more general `Ecdf` function from the [**Hmisc**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Hmisc) has a `what=` option for that:

> Arguments:
>
> ```
>    x: a numeric vector, data frame, or Trellis/Lattice formula
>
> what: The default is ‘"F"’ which results in plotting the fraction
>       of values <= x.  Set to ‘"1-F"’ to plot the fraction > x or
>       ‘"f"’ to plot the cumulative frequency of values <= x.
> ```

So with that we can modify the answer [from your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474808/howto-plot-two-cumulative-frequency-graph-together) and add `what="1-F"`:

```
 # Example showing how to draw multiple ECDFs from paired data
 pre.test <- rnorm(100,50,10)
 post.test <- rnorm(100,55,10)
 x <- c(pre.test, post.test)
 g <- c(rep('Pre',length(pre.test)),rep('Post',length(post.test)))
 Ecdf(x, group=g, what="1-F", xlab='Test Results', label.curves=list(keys=1:2))
```

Comment: @Dirk: I am aware of "1-F" option, what I intend to get is the reverse "Frequency" not proportion. Hence I mentioned (1-f), small-f.

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- data.frame(x, g)
df$y <- apply(df, 1, function(v){nrow(subset(df, g == v[2] & x >= v[1]))})
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x, y, data=df, geom='line', colour=g)
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have only one vector `x`, then you can do the following:

```
f <- ecdf(x)
plot(1-f(x),x)
```