# R: bar plot with two groups, of which one is stacked

Tags: r, grouping, bar-chart

I've encountered a small problem when creating a bar plot in R. There are 3 variables:

```
a <- c(3,3,2,1,0)
b <- c(3,2,2,2,2)
c <- 0:4
```

The bar plot should be grouped by 'a' and 'c', and 'b' should be stacked on top of 'a'. Doing the grouping and stacking seperately is straightforward:

```
barplot(rbind(a,c), beside=TRUE)
barplot(rbind(a,b), beside=FALSE)
```

How can you do both at once in one graph?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801064/how-to-separate-two-plots-in-r

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Doing this requires thinking about how `barplot` draws stacked bars. Basically, you need to feed it some data with 0 values in appropriate places. With your data:

```
mydat <- cbind(rbind(a,b,0),rbind(0,0,c))[,c(1,6,2,7,3,8,4,9,5,10)]
barplot(mydat,space=c(.75,.25))
```

[image: barplot]

To see what's going on under the hood, take a look at `mydat`:

```
> mydat
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
a    3    0    3    0    2    0    1    0    0     0
b    3    0    2    0    2    0    2    0    2     0
     0    0    0    1    0    2    0    3    0     4
```

Here, you're plotting each bar with three values (the value of `a`, the value of `b`, the value of `c`). Each column of the `mydat` matrix is a bar, sorted so that the ab bars are appropriately interspersed with the c bars. You may want to play around with spacing and color.

Apparently versions of this have been discussed on R-help [various](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-June/053210.html) [times](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-July/023755.html) [without](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-January/225082.html) [great](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-January/185501.html) [solutions](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-March/350299.html), so hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: Yea, this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks. Any chance you could show me the equivalent ggplot?

Comment: @Forzaa I actually don't use ggplot, so I can't be any help there.

Comment: No worries; I'll look into that myself. Thanks again, though!

Answer (score 0):

Try the `lattice` lib:

```
library("lattice")
MyData <- as.data.frame(Titanic)

barchart(Freq ~ Survived | Age * Sex, groups = Class, data = MyData,
         auto.key = list(points = FALSE, rectangles = TRUE, space
         = "right", title = "Class", border = TRUE), xlab = "Survived",
         ylim = c(0, 800))
```

[image: output]

As you can see the grouping and ploting is done at once.

Please also see: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-June/053216.html

Comment: There is no stacking on top of each other in this example, so it does not really achieve my goal.