# R: barplot with n groups which stacks 2 values

Tags: r, bar-chart

I need to generate a **barplot** which consists of the following:

**I have a csv file with columns: Category Reason Time Value**

- Category has 7 possible names (c1 ... c7)
- Reason has 8 possible names (n1 ... n8)
- Time has 2 possible names (T1, T2)
- Value is the time value

Example dataset:

```
Category    Reason  Time    Value
C1  R1  T1  1
C2  R1  T2  2
C1  R2  T1  3
C2  R2  T2  4
C1  R3  T1  8
C2  R3  T2  0
```

**What i want to achieve:**
A bar plot which consists of 3 groups (i.e. one group per REASON), where each group consists of 2 stacked bars (i.e. a bar for each CATEGORY), where each bar depicts T1 and T2 on top of it.

I guess i need something similar as [R: bar plot with two groups, of which one is stacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081102/r-bar-plot-with-two-groups-of-which-one-is-stacked), but unfortunately i'm very new to R.

**Similar to this picture, which has in terms of my example:**

- 5 categories
- 3 reasons
- 4 times values
- % as a time value

[image: Example]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is a good habit to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610) in your question. Furthermore: adding what you have tried and possible error message(s) are also highly appreciated. Including these aspects will make it easier for other people to help you and will increase the chance that you get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Besides loading the csv and displaying a dataframe on a plot, i don't know much more, such as on how to group particular columns together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to introduce you to the `ggplot` package in R which may give you a better way of visualizing your problem. Even if it does not solve your current problem, `ggplot` would be the easiest for starting your visualizations in R.

First the code:

`library` will load `ggplot` and `scales` package

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
```

Generating your dummy data set

```
df = expand.grid(factor(c("C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C6","C8")),
                 factor(c("R1","R2","R3","R4","R5","R6","R7")),
                 factor(c("T1","T2")))
```

Plot with `Category` on x-axis, `Value` on y-axis, `Time` as the stacked bar which needs `geom_bar()`. Instead of grouping on the bar chart itself, `ggplot` can use `facets`, which produces cleaner results. `scale_y_continuous()` converts your y-axis to percent.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Reason, y=Value, fill = Time)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  facet_wrap(~Category) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

[image]

Comment: I get on windows: Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’

Comment: You need to install packages before you use them. Run `install.packages(ggplot2)` and `install.packages(scales)`

Comment: This works and i prefer the grid style, but is there a way to have a white background, and have each REASON on the x-axis (i don't need the 1..8 on the x-axis (which are the categories), but i need per group the only and single reason beneath it)

Comment: You have 1-7 categories on the x-axis and one reason for the group. Check the edited answer again.

Comment: No, i don't want to numbers 1-7, i want to replace that by "reason1" for the first grup, "reason2" for the second group. I also want a clean white background, i.e. i don't want them to be visually grouped in those gray grids. Is the gray box on top the reason? If so, can you put it below the graph?

Comment: + How do i use the "read.csv" in combination with "expand.grid"?

Comment: As per the edited answer, the groups are now `Category` `C1-C8`. You have `Reason` on the x-axis. In case you want groups of `Reason`, just interchange `Reason` and `Category` in the `ggplot` script. The background is white. I would encourage you to visit http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/ for more customizations per your choice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111935/discussion-between-divi-and-captain-obvious).

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind sharing a version of your .csv file? Without that my guess looks something like this...

```
p_csv <- read.table(file.csv, header = T, sep = ",")

library(ggplot2)
#using mtcars 
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(cyl))) +
geom_bar(aes(fill = as.factor(gear)))
```

I"m happy help more if I can see some test data :)

Still not 100% on what you are trying to do with the time value, but this might be sufficient. I adjusted you sample data slightly so time and category wouldn't always be in sync.

```
df <- data.frame("category" = c("C1", "C2", "C1", "C2", "C1", "C2"),
             "reason" = c("R1", "R1", "R2", "R2", "R3", "R3"),
             "time" = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2"),
             "value" = c(1,2,3,4,8,0))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = as.factor(reason), y = value)) +
geom_bar(aes(fill = as.factor(category)), stat = "identity") +
facet_grid(~time)
```

Comment: It's confidential data, but i need to use the barplot function. I will try to recreate an example csv

Comment: I've added a dataset example in the post.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and time, but do you know how I can do this using the barplot function in R. Also the time-value is just an integer which will be displayed on the y-axis, the x-axis would contain the names of the different groups.